# Display categories

Tags: smarty, categories

I have my website working on social engine, I have a Main page named as `articles.tpl`, and in that I have a sub-page named as `article.tpl`, `article.tpl` is used to show the entire article, and `articles.tpl` is used to show topics of articles not the content,

My concern is with articles.tpl(pretty confusing articles and article)
In `articles.tpl`, 3 articles title, author of article and date is displayed, but I also want to display the category of that article,

For that I tried the following code,

```
$article_category = "";
$parent_category = "";
$article_category_query = $database->database_query("SELECT articlecat_id, articlecat_title, ".
        "articlecat_dependency FROM se_articlecats WHERE articlecat_id='".
        $rc_article->article_info[article_articlecat_id]."' LIMIT 1");

if($database->database_num_rows($article_category_query) == 1) {

    $article_category_info = $database->database_fetch_assoc($article_category_query);

    $article_category = $article_category_info[articlecat_title];

    if($article_category_info[articlecat_dependency] != 0) {

    $parent_category = $database->database_fetch_assoc(
            $database->database_query("SELECT articlecat_id, articlecat_title".
            " FROM se_articlecats WHERE articlecat_id='".
            $article_category_info[articlecat_dependency]."' LIMIT 1"));
    }
}
$smarty->assign('article_category', $article_category);
```

and in `articles.tpl` file I called it in this way

```
<span class="tahoma11_blue">|  {$article_category}</span>
```

But when I check I get nothing, that space is blank, I am just able to see
|

How can I display the category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to change

```
$smarty->assign('categories', $categories);
```

to

```
$smarty->assign('article_category', $article_category);
```

(in your example, you assign the (apparently empty) php variable `$categories` to the smarty variable `categories`. then, in the template, you use a smarty variable `article_category` - which never got assigned)

Comment: @ax Hey I edited that too(check my question), but still the category is not getting displayed

Comment: please show us some debug output (`var_dump()`). what are the values of `$article_category_info`, `$article_category`, etc. btw: `$article_category = $article_category_info[articlecat_title];` should be `$article_category = $article_category_info['articlecat_title'];` (note the quotes around articlecat_title). same for all other `$array[string_key]` in your code.

Comment: @ax hey I am new to smarty, I have put the quotes as you said, but still the same,
sorry to ask you but can you come in chat or can you take this question to chat?

Comment: @ax I added var_dump
and in return it gave me  this output string(0) ""
I tried this code `{$article_category|var_dump}`

Comment: put the `var_dump()` in the php code, *not* in the template, after the variables are assigned, eg. `var_dump($article_category_info)` after `$article_category_info = ...` (and maybe an `exit;` after the last `var_dump()` so you can see the values).

Comment: for taking this question to chat, you will have to hire me :)

Comment: @ax hire ?? in the sense what?

Comment: did you make any progress in solving your problem?